# How to get user access token through its uid?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

lets say i have app id, app secret id and user uid now i want to get user access token to get its locations information. Actually i am listening for real time updates for user status if user changes its status i received that update on my server which is node.js server now i have its user uid i want to retrieve information about its updates but for that i need user access token and i am not getting how to get that?

Note: User already authorize this app for user_status permissions through facebook so i have access permissions to its location info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the access token with user id. You have to get the extended access token and store that some where and you can use it later.

Now, you should be able to access the status with application access token. I had earlier got email of my all users with application access token as they had granted permission to app.

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials

This will return you application access token.

Comment: extended access token and application access token are same if not so how can i get extended access toke. grant_type=client_credentials does i need to put user uid here instead of client_credentials

Comment: I get application access token through url you provide now when i want to get user locations like this https://graph.facebook.com/1255434277/locations?access_token=MyAppaccessToken it gives me following error A user access token is required to request this resource.

Comment: extended user access token and app access token are different. FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

for application accesss, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: do you have user_location permission?

Comment: your answer shows me the direction about solving this issue thanks